# C++ How to pass 2 arrays (of strings) to a function, and compare to a string

Tags: c++, arrays, function

**I'm a C++ beginner, so talk to me like I'm 5.**

Here's what I'm trying to do:

- Take user's input into a string `userInput`
- Pass `userInput`, along with 2 arrays (`answers` and `outcomes`), into a function `answerCheck`
- Compare `userInput` with `answers` array
- If there's a match, output string from `outcomes`
- If no match, loop, ask for `userInput`

I output the size of `answers` with `answersSize`.  It outputs 1 instead of the expected 2.

I can't figure out how to pass the information in the arrays to the `answerCheck` function.

Any suggestions?

```cs
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int question1();
bool answerCheck(string[], string[], string);

int main() {

    question1();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int question1() {

    cout << "Do you want to go LEFT or RIGHT?" << endl;

    string answers[2] = { "left", "right" }; 
    string outcomes[2] = { "you went left", "you went right" }; 
    string userInput = ""; 

    getline(cin, userInput);

    // outputs correct size of answers array for testing ======
    int answersSize = sizeof(answers) / sizeof(string); 
    cout << "Correct size of answers: "<< answersSize << endl;
    // ========================================================

    answerCheck(answers, outcomes, userInput);

    return 0;
}


bool answerCheck(string answers[], string outcomes[], string userInput){ 

    int answersSize = sizeof(answers) / sizeof(string); 

    cout << "Size of answers: "<< answersSize << endl;

    for(int i=0; i < answersSize; i++){ 

        if(userInput.find(answers[i]) != string::npos){

            cout <<"\n" << outcomes[i] <<"\n" << endl;
            return true;
        }
    }

    cout << "Try putting in something else." << endl;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Never write `string answers[]` in a function header, because it looks like an array, but it's actually not an array - it actually means the same as `string *answers`. (Yes, the standards committee must have been feeling particularly braindead when they decided that)

Comment: @immibis when the first standard was published it was important not to break too much existing code, otherwise the standard would not be adopted widely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general advice for beginners would be to use the C++ such as classes `std::vector` instead of plain C arrays. So in your example, instead of

```
string answers[2] = { "left", "right" };
```

use

```
std::vector<std::string> answers{ "left", "right" };
```

and declare your function

```
bool answerCheck(std::vector<string> const& answers, 
                 std::vector<string> const&outcomes, 
                 string const& userInput)
```

If you are reading a introductory book and it starts by introducing C-style code first, I would throw it away. A good introduction to C++ is e.g. https://isocpp.org/tour.

Comment: Vectors seems to be the way to go.  I got it to work, but I didn't use the const& (references, I think?) in my code.  Still worked.  If you feel like explaining that, feel free.

Comment: @KevinB. The code will work without references. When you pass an object by value, the compiler will create a copy and use that copy in the function. Using a const-reference saves the copy because you are passing a reference to the existing object which cannot be modified. It is a general rule of thumb that you pass objects by `const&` if you do not store it or modify it. I would recommend that you get a copy of a good book because it also explains the rationals behind things like this. The Tour of C++ should be good.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll look into Tour of C++.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
int answersSize = sizeof(answers) / sizeof(string);
```

If you print it out, you will find that `sizeof(answers)` is the size of a pointer (4 or 8 bytes), not the size of the entire array.  You need to pass the array size in as a function argument, or else use a class type like `std::vector` which encapsulates this in a more C++ way.

Comment: so if you use a string[] it is impossible to determine the array size with code after passing it it through a function?

Comment: @Danny: correct.  Because the array is passed by pointer, and a pointer isn't enough to figure out the array length.